# ¿Porque cuando aplico efecto parallax a un background se mueve de mas?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, background, parallax

Cunado le aplico el efecto parallax a mi imagen se vel el movimiento pero conforme avanza la parte de abajo va desapareciendo y deja espacio vacio donde deberia verse el resto de la imagen

Lo estoy haciendo Codepen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="contenedor-imagen">
  <div class="parallax" id="parallax">
    <!--<h3 class="titulo" id="titulo">Titulo con Parallax</h3>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
body .contenedor-imagen{
  position: relative;
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 800px;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

body .contenedor-imagen .parallax{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1aiBjGL3hKZWW27juZsBU6ZiAdSJfpa_y);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```
var parallax = document.querySelector("#parallax");
var titulo = document.querySelector("#titulo");

function scrollParallax(){
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  //titulo.style.transform = "translateY(" + scrollTop * -0.8 + "px)";
  alturaAnimado = parallax.offsetTop;
  //if(alturaAnimado  + 300 <= scrollTop){
    parallax.style.transform = "translateY(" + scrollTop * -0.2 + "px)";
  //}
  
  
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollParallax);
```

Comment: Ese codigo que pones en la imagen debes colocarlo como texto, el uso de imagenes es para demostrar un concepto o aclarar algo respecto el codigo, mas no para mostrar tu codigo, tu codigo debe ir como texto formateado en tu pregunta, porfavor editala.

Comment: Bienvenido, el código agrégalo como texto ya que no es visible para toda la comunidad, revisa [ask]y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, lo modificare :D